# How to debug under Olly the Windows 8.1 Store apps?

Tags: windows, ollydbg, debugging, windows-8

Ive tried to attach to some windows store app. It seems like there is no way
since when OllyDebugger stopped reacting, showing the 'Loading .udd data' message. If I re-launch olly, it reacts the same way. The only difference is that it may be different .udd file... What to do further I do not know.
   I pointed out the correct .UDD directory(which is the same where my ollydbg saved).